# random, strings and intergers in python

Tags: python, string, random

Write python program that generates 3 random numbers between 1 and 10 one hundred times. The program should display each set of 3 numbers on a new line separated by commas. An example output should be formatted as follows:

```
Number set 1 is: 10,7,8   
Number set 2 is: 4,6,5
...  
Number set 100 is: 7,3,1
```

I need help displaying it correctly.
3 random numbers 100 times.

---

```
import random

mylist = [random.randint(1,11) for r in range(100)]
x = random.sample(mylist,3)
for i in range(100):
    print('Number set', i + 1, 'is', x)
```

Comment: You should make sure that you're generating unique random numbers for each iteration. The example code generates a random set, but then doesn't update it within the loop itself.

Comment: do you want sets with no duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem:

These lines of code are  outside of your loop. This means that the **numbers are not going to be unique every time you run the code** and will stay the same for all iterations of your loop.

```py
mylist = [random.randint(1,11) for r in range(100)]
x = random.sample(mylist,3)
```

#### Solution:

You could move the previous mentioned lines in your code to be inside your loop rather than outside:

```py
import random

for i in range(100):
    mylist = [random.randint(1,11) for r in range(100)]
    x = random.sample(mylist,3)
    print('Number set', i + 1, 'is', x)
```

Or you could write a cleaner solution:

```py
import random

for i in range(1,101):
    print(f"Number set {i} is: {random.randint(1,11)},{random.randint(1,11)},{random.randint(1,11)}")
```

Rather than using a list this solution will print a formatted string 100 times of 3 different random numbers. This will loop over 100 times.

You could also take a look at the other answer choices too.

`random.choices()` and `random.sample()` are good options too.

read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

Answer (score 1):

An even shorter answer would be:

```
import random
for x in range(100):
  print('Number set', x , 'is', random.sample(range(1, 11), 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want random numbers in array you should put `random.sample()` in loop

```
import random

mylist = [random.randint(1,11) for r in range(100)]
for i in range(100):
    x = random.sample(mylist,3)
    print('Number set', i + 1, 'is', x)
```

output is like

```
...
Number set 98 is [4, 3, 1]                                                                                                
Number set 99 is [11, 11, 4]                                                                                              
Number set 100 is [8, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The another easiest way is `random.choices()`,try:

```
print(*[random.choices(range(1, 11), k=3) for i in range(100)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `x` is being printed as a list. 
What you'll need to do it convert the list in to a string and join them by `','`s

```
import random

l = ','.join(str(i) for i in x)` and use l in your loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimalist answer:

```
from random import sample

for i in range(100):
    print('Number set {i+1} is:', ','.join(sample([str(n) for n in range(1,11)],3)))
```

---

You can use this code to dynamically choose how many numbers will be in each set:

```
from random import randint as rd

n = 3 # Choose the amount

for i in range(1,101):
    print(f"Number set {i} is:",','.join(f"{rd(1,11)}" for _ in range(n)))
```

Output:

```
Number set 1 is: 8,1,1
Number set 2 is: 9,2,11
Number set 3 is: 4,2,9
Number set 4 is: 6,8,9
Number set 5 is: 8,9,8
Number set 6 is: 11,6,10
Number set 7 is: 10,1,7
Number set 8 is: 4,4,7
Number set 9 is: 9,1,4
Number set 10 is: 1,1,11
Number set 11 is: 6,4,7
Number set 12 is: 9,11,11
Number set 13 is: 11,9,5
Number set 14 is: 6,2,11
Number set 15 is: 7,1,4
Number set 16 is: 11,9,5
Number set 17 is: 9,2,4
Number set 18 is: 5,1,8
Number set 19 is: 5,5,6
Number set 20 is: 5,1,5
Number set 21 is: 1,2,6
Number set 22 is: 8,3,4
Number set 23 is: 3,6,4
Number set 24 is: 5,1,11
Number set 25 is: 7,9,1
Number set 26 is: 10,2,7
Number set 27 is: 9,7,1
Number set 28 is: 11,4,8
Number set 29 is: 10,7,1
Number set 30 is: 2,11,3
Number set 31 is: 3,11,8
Number set 32 is: 2,5,11
Number set 33 is: 9,7,5
Number set 34 is: 9,8,11
Number set 35 is: 1,11,4
Number set 36 is: 8,9,2
Number set 37 is: 6,3,7
Number set 38 is: 8,5,11
Number set 39 is: 7,10,8
Number set 40 is: 10,9,5
Number set 41 is: 9,5,4
Number set 42 is: 10,9,9
Number set 43 is: 1,1,6
Number set 44 is: 10,9,5
Number set 45 is: 7,7,10
Number set 46 is: 9,8,10
Number set 47 is: 9,5,6
Number set 48 is: 7,10,10
Number set 49 is: 6,2,7
Number set 50 is: 9,7,9
Number set 51 is: 11,10,1
Number set 52 is: 2,7,4
Number set 53 is: 11,2,6
Number set 54 is: 2,1,3
Number set 55 is: 9,5,10
Number set 56 is: 6,2,8
Number set 57 is: 1,7,9
Number set 58 is: 8,8,9
Number set 59 is: 5,2,2
Number set 60 is: 8,2,10
Number set 61 is: 4,11,10
Number set 62 is: 8,7,9
Number set 63 is: 3,9,7
Number set 64 is: 8,3,5
Number set 65 is: 10,3,9
Number set 66 is: 9,8,2
Number set 67 is: 7,1,9
Number set 68 is: 10,11,11
Number set 69 is: 1,6,11
Number set 70 is: 2,2,6
Number set 71 is: 10,1,8
Number set 72 is: 6,6,9
Number set 73 is: 7,7,2
Number set 74 is: 4,6,11
Number set 75 is: 4,11,9
Number set 76 is: 8,6,5
Number set 77 is: 11,11,3
Number set 78 is: 2,7,6
Number set 79 is: 11,2,8
Number set 80 is: 4,4,10
Number set 81 is: 5,2,8
Number set 82 is: 9,1,10
Number set 83 is: 10,7,7
Number set 84 is: 11,4,5
Number set 85 is: 7,9,1
Number set 86 is: 6,9,2
Number set 87 is: 2,8,7
Number set 88 is: 6,11,7
Number set 89 is: 6,2,10
Number set 90 is: 8,7,1
Number set 91 is: 3,6,1
Number set 92 is: 10,5,9
Number set 93 is: 3,9,6
Number set 94 is: 7,7,7
Number set 95 is: 11,5,9
Number set 96 is: 10,1,1
Number set 97 is: 11,1,10
Number set 98 is: 7,1,2
Number set 99 is: 5,3,5
Number set 100 is: 1,6,2
```